# How can I control my wifi web surfing?

Tags: wireless-networking

Is there a way that I can control my wifi internet browsing. I got many children visiting me with their families and they use laptops, tablets, mobile phones, etc to surf the web on my broadband WiFi Network. Is there a way that I can block some types of sites in my broadband WiFi?

Comment: Are you trying to block websites or limit the amount of time one can be on the internet?

Comment: Have you tried [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=parental+control+software&oq=parental+control+software&g)?

Comment: I want to block some types of websites.

Answer (score 0):

Quick-n-Dirty: Set your router to use opendns and filter the categories you desire. You can always turn it off later.

https://store.opendns.com/get/home-free

Comment: That was difficult. Need something easier

Comment: Takes about 5 minutes to protect every device on your network.  This includes iPod, laptops, etc.  the only easier method is to unplug your Internet while they're in town.

Comment: I did not manage to be able to change the DNS. It can not be changed in my BT Hub settings. This is the problem!

Comment: Sorry about that then... Looks like BT locks things down pretty tight which makes opendns difficult... http://punj-technology.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-opendns-with-bt-homehub-broadband.html?m=1

Comment: OpenDNS difficult? You may want to consult a third party IT company.